# Did Demosthenes complain about inflation of prices in philippics?

Tags: ancient-greece, economy

Did [Demosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosthenes) complain about inflation of prices in his philippics caused by [Philip II of Macedon's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_II_of_Macedon) extensive gold mining?

I have heard it somewhere but I can not find any refference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each of the Philippics, Demosthenes rails against Philip's underhandedness and his fellow citizens' cowardice and complacency. References to money are generally confined to questions of raising funds for war and there is no reference to gold mining by Philip. The [fourth Philippic](http://www.kingsacademy.com/mhodges/08_Classics-Library/greece/demosthenes/philippic-04.htm) talks the most about money, and in that, Demosthenes indicates that inflation is not a problem:

> If therefore, noting the abundance and cheapness of goods for sale in
>   your markets, you have been beguiled by these things into the belief
>   that the city is in no danger, your estimate of the situation is
>   contrary to all right and reason.

Answer (score -4):

Never heard of the guy before. However, the wiki page you linked said:

> Demosthenes grew interested in politics during his time as a
>   logographer, and in 354 BC he gave his first public political
>   speeches. He went on to devote his most productive years to opposing
>   Macedon's expansion.

So basicaly, he was an anti-Macedonian political pundit.

You only have to watch a few minutes of this type of person today to realise that they will make any argument available that they think might advance their point. So if he noticed an inflationary effect, or even the hint of one, or even something that could be argued with a bit of work to make it look like there was one, he would have made that argument.

So, while it would be nice to find the actual reference, if nothing else we can say it certianly would have been in character for the guy.

Comment: wish I had 125 reputation...

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek It requires that much to flag an an answer? :-)

Comment: nope, to vote it down ;)

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek - I tried to help you out, but it won't let me downvote my own answer. :-)

Comment: :)))))))))))) ... seriously, I was like BIG LOL when I read "Never heard of that guy before" :)

Comment: @T.E.D.: As a completely unrelated observation, you sure seem to have missed some great books by O.S. Card :)

Comment: @kubanczyk - Yeah, my non-fiction history library is far better flushed out than my (mostly my wife's but I read them too) SF/F library.

Comment: -1 Well, frankly, this isn't really a good answer, @daniel.sedlacek definitely has a point. Nothing personal of course (your answers are usually quite good, this one surprised me).

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted this one too.